# How to bind existing dropdown list defined in .aspx with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu, c#-3.0

I have a dropdown list in design page as shown below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArtList" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Value="95">Select</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This items above are sometimes overridden by some other values in C#, according to the requirement.
But at the end i want to bind the above default items with the help of C# to get the above listitems.

I want to know is there any In-Built method or attribute to bind the dropdownlist(.aspx) in C#.

Without using this: ddlArtList.Items.Add ("1); etc etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AppendDataBoundItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**.aspx Code**:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArtList" AppendDataBoundItems="True" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Value="95">Select</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**ServerSide**:

```
ddlArtList.AppendDataBoundItems="True"
```

Comment: Values are not overriding the other. infact all the values are getting bind to the dropdownlist.

Comment: @Pranav can you show in your code how you are binding or adding new items to it

Comment: ClientSide: would be aspx or html side. As the <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArtList" AppendDataBoundItems="True"  ... is server side code

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the default list in Session during first Page Load -

```
if(!isPostback)
{
    ListItem[] items = new ListItem[ddlArtList.Items.Count];
    ddlArtList.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
    Session["ddlArtList"] = items;
}
```

Now when you want to reset the list -

```
if(Session["ddlArtList"] != null)
{
    ListItem[] items = Session["ddlArtList"] as ListItem[];
    ddlArtList.Items.Clear();
    ddlArtList.Items.AddRange(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to a default list, use the markup as you provided to set the default list.  You will want to set AppendDataBoundItems to true, as already mentioned.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArtList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="95">Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

In the code-behind, you can set the DataSource to the appended items and simply call DataBind.  That will append those items to your dropdownlist.

```
ddlArtList.DataSource = new List<int>{ 10, 11, 12 }; // replace with actual data source you are using
ddlArtList.DataBind();
```

Depending on all of your needs, you can add those appended items on the page's Load event or inside another event handler, such as a button click or selecting from another dropdownlist or whatever.

Comment: No I did this in Visual Studio and it works just fine.